How can I solve [firebase_functions/internal] INTERNAL?
I've uploaded a Firebase function (code below) which uses Google Gemini API to generate workouts. Then, I use Dart to call it but, even though I've allowed public access to call it, it throws this error:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/internal] INTERNAL

#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:22:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      new GenerateWorkoutBloc.<anonymous closure> (package:energi/logic/blocs/generate_workout/generate_workout_bloc.dart:50:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure>.handleEvent (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:229:13)

I've allowed public access otherwise it showed a Firebase UNAUTHENITCATED error. Now I don't know what INTERNAL stands for, so I would love it if you could explain it to me.
Here is the function:
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { GoogleGenerativeAI } = require("@google/generative-ai");

const apiKey = "key"; 
const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(apiKey);

const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({
  model: "gemini-1.5-pro",
});

const generationConfig = {
  temperature: 1.7,
  topP: 0.95,
  topK: 64,
  maxOutputTokens: 8192,
  responseMimeType: "application/json",
};

exports.generateWorkout = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('starting');
    const chatSession = model.generateContent({
      generationConfig,
      history: [
        {
          role: "user",
          parts: [
            {text: "You are a professional...."},
          ],
        },
        {
          role: "model",
          parts: [
            {text: "```json\....`"},
          ],
        },
      ],
    });
  
    const result = (await chatSession).response;
    const responseText = await result.response.text();
    console.log(responseText);
    res.status(200).send(responseText);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating workout:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Error generating workout");
  }
});

And here is how I call it:
try {
        HttpsCallable callable =
            FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('generateWorkout');
        final response = await callable.call();
        print(response);

      } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
        print(error.toString());

      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
      }


What?
In my experience this means that something in your Cloud Function execution is failing.
Solution
To troubleshoot the issue I would do the following:

Ensure I have good logging inside the generateWorkout Cloud Function.
Visit the Cloud Functions GCP page and enter the generateWorkout function page.
There I would tap the Logs tab.
Lastly I would read the logs to understand what that my function was having.

Let me know if this helps!

Thanks for your answer. The problem was inside of the function I wrote. I was using the sendMesssage function instead of generateContent regarding Gemini AI usage. This led to a wrong interpretation and usage of the remain code

Glad I could help, happy coding!
